# How can i get username input in maiActivity to 3rd TabActivity

Tags: android

I am a new android developer and writing an application. Login page in main activity and three tab activity are another activities. I want username input field which is in mainActivity and wants it in 3rd tabActivity, how can I get this?

Comment: Please show your code, and what you've tried so far...?

Comment: still did not do anything. actualy when user login.i want to show his all details in 3rdTab Activity.but how i query in tabActivity using username or password.